# Android Studio quick doc window size

Tags: android, android-studio

I have trouble in Android Studio. When I mouse over variables or methods Quick Doc view was popup as image below.

[image]

Quick doc window width is all size of screen.
But I'm need small window as red rectangle.
How can I change Quick Doc's window size?

Comment: I'd like to remind close-voters that questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is" ... "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and don't belong on SuperUser.

Comment: Does Window, Restore Default Layout solve the problem?

Comment: Same problem occur to me! The window's width is infinite as your picture below.

Answer (score 3):

I have SOLVED this problem.

Step 1: Drag the documentation window's title bar and move to left until you can see the window's right edge.

Step 2: Move the mouse to the right edge as the mouse change to resize status what is seem like showing in micro word document's table edge.

Step 3: Just move mouse to left to make window's width narrow and repeat this action. REMEMBER: The window cannot disappear otherwise you have to do it again until success.

NOTE: you can also resize the window with the bottom right corner. You can see a little triangle that is the resize magic area.

Comment: I noticed that only resize from "bottom right corner" working. If you resize from "right corner", the size of quick doc will be resumed back as previous state when you click the quick doc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually.

1. Click on title-bar of Quick-Doc window and drag it to the left side until its right edge is visible.
2. Now drag right edge of the window to resize it.

Shortcut for quick dock window  is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: I try this. But unfortunately window width is infinity.

Comment: infinity? I don't think it is possible. One more option, you can drag from right to left. Again you have to do it many times :(